# Assigning Process to Cores using Perl

Tags: perl, process, multicore, parallel-processing

How can I assign processes to specific cores ?.  I have a 16 core machine and need to assign processes to multiple cores rather then all/few of them running on same cores.

Can Parallel::ForkManager do this ?. or How do you do it with using standard perl distribution ?

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't your OS automatically distribute the processes between the cores in the most efficient manner? You should not normally have to deal with issues as low-level as this.

Comment: when you run the program it's arbitrary sometimes 2 cores take all the 16 processes sometime 1/3. This is when the system has minimum background process and computation. Point is I was to explicitly have one process to one core assignment.

Comment: You can check Forks::Super mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051479/perl-fork-queue-for-n-core-processor?lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Windows, you can use `Win32::Process`, it has a subroutine called `SetProcessAffinityMask`, which should do what you want.

Under Linux, take a look at `Sys::CpuAffinity`.