# Perl fork queue for n-Core processor

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, queue, fork, multicore

I am writing an application similar to what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231833/in-perl-how-can-i-block-for-a-bunch-of-system-calls-to-finish/2232057). Essentially, I am using Perl to manage the execution of multiple CPU intensive processes in parallel via fork and wait. However, I am running on a 4-core machine, and I have many more processes, all with very dissimilar expected run-times which aren't known a priori.

Ultimately, it would take more effort to estimate the run times and gang them appropriately, than to simply utilize a queue system for each core. Ultimately I want each core to be processing, with as little downtime as possible, until everything is done. Is there a preferred algorithm or mechanism for doing this? I would assume this is a common problem/use so I don't want to re-invent the wheel, as my wheel will probably be inferior to the 'right way. '

As a minor aside, I would prefer to not have to import additional modules (like [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager)) to accomplish this, but if that is the best way to go, then I will consider it.

~Thanks!

**EDIT:** Fixed 'here' link: Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)

**EDIT:** P::FM is too easy to use, not to... Today I Learned.

Comment: So you're asking for us to copy P::FM here?!

Comment: Incorrect link for "here".

Comment: I think this module can help you [Sys::CpuAffinity](http://search.cpan.org/~mob/Sys-CpuAffinity-1.05/lib/Sys/CpuAffinity.pm)

Comment: The whole idea of Perl is reusing someone else's code. That usually comes in modules, so go ahead and load them. They don't really cost you anything. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I indeed see the benefit to using others code, hence the question in the first place :) I am hesitant to use external sources due to the nature of my development/operation environment. It is highly distributed and heterogenous; and I need the solution to be preferably small, portable, and version/dependency agnostic... but this may be the best way to go, so I will pursue it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Forks::Super`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Forks%3a%3aSuper) has some features that are good for this sort of task.

- **extended syntax, but not a lot of new syntax**: if you already have a program with `fork` and `wait` calls, you can still use the features of `Forks::Super` without too many changes. That is, your new code will still have `fork` and `wait` calls.
- **job throttling**: like `Parallel::ForkManager`, you can control how many jobs you run simultaneously. When one job completes, the module can start another one, keeping your system fully utilized. You can also specify more complex logic like "run at most 6 background jobs on the weekends or between midnight and 6:00 am, but 2 background jobs the rest of the time"
- **timing utilities:** `Forks::Super` keeps track of the start time and end time of every job, letting you log and analyze how long each job took:

  ```
  fork { cmd => "some command" };
  ...
  $pid = wait;
  $elapsed = $pid->{end} - $pid->{start};
  print LOG "That job took ${elapsed}s\n";
  ```
- **CPU affinity control:** I can't tell whether this is something you need, but Guarav seemed to think it mattered. You can assign background jobs to specific cores

  ```
  # restrict job to cores #0 and #2
  $job = fork { sub => \&background_process, args => \@args, 
                cpu_affinity => 0x05 };
  ```

Comment: Thanks a ton! I hadn't heard about [`Forks::Super`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Forks::Super), I will look into it and see if I can tease a solution out of it.